# Ошибка парсера и не определяются переменные(sass)

Tags: sass

Здравствуйте!
1) Почему не определяются мои переменные, хотя все файлы подключаются в один?
2) Что за ошибка в консоли, как исправить ее?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @OlmerDale, = ставится при объявлении миксина, зачем импортировать переменные в тот файл в котором они используются, если все это потом окажется в 1 файле.

Comment: Попробуйте файлу `_icon-circle` добавить разрешение.  Ошибка говорит о том, что парсер наткнулся на знак, которого там быть не должно.

Comment: @YuS, как это сделать, не было необходимости?

Comment: Как добавить расширение файлу? Переименовать файл и дописать вконец `.sass` :)

Comment: @YuS, если заметили, то там .sass

Comment: *расширение. Проклятый Т9.

Comment: Нет, не заметил. На вкладке и в ошибке `_icon-circle` без `.sass`